# getRangeAt(0) returns #text node with parentNode document-fragment

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the selected node. Let's say I got all selected "CLICK TO EDIT".

```
<span style="text-transform: lowercase">CLICK TO EDIT</span>
```

Attempt to grab the current selection through:

```
var select = window.getSelection();
var range = select.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
var selectedNode = range.cloneContents().childNodes[0];
```

In some cases, selectedNode is a `#text` node containing "CLICK TO EDIT" instead of a SPAN element.

What I want is the span containing this text node. But `selectedNode.parentNode` is a `document-fragment`, `selectedNode.parentElement` is **null**.

How am I supposed to get the span element in this case then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code listens for `selectionchange` events, and gets the parent element of the selected text.

```js
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', e => {
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  var anchorNode = selection.anchorNode;
  
  if (anchorNode) {
    // This is the <span>, when you select the text
    var parentElement = anchorNode.parentElement;
    console.log(parentElement);
  }
});
```

```html
<span style="text-transform: lowercase">CLICK TO EDIT</span>
```